# Postgresql jsonb_agg with multiple json

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

Hi i'm using jsonb_agg for create array of objects. But when i want to create it with multiple json im getting this error.

```
ERROR:  function jsonb_agg(json, json) does not exist
```

This is what im trying to do

```sql
SELECT 
    station.id AS "objectID",
    station.name AS "objectName",
    station.activity,
    'Station'::text AS unit,
    jsonb_agg(
     json_build_object('key'::text, 'value'::text),
     json_build_object('key'::text, 'value'::text),
     ...
    ) AS "childrenList"
    FROM eqp_stations station
```

Is there any way to merge multiple json into array of objects

I hard coded json key and value pairs but I am going to fill these areas later.

Expected Json object like

```json
{
 "objectId":123,
 "objectName":"blabla",
 "unit":"Station",
 "childrenList": [
   {"key":"value"},
   {"key":"value"},
   ...
  ]
 
}
```

Comment: it's pretty obvious that you have a `jsonb` function with arguments returning `json` values. You might try `json(b)_build_object` functions as arguments...

Comment: Post how the expected json looks like and explain why are 'key' and 'value' hardcoded?

Comment: I will fill the key value pairs with join statements. ı added expected output @SalmanA

Comment: I suppose `json_agg` could be replaced with `jsonb_build_array` and that is is, assuming you know the number of children in advance.

Comment: How are we supposed to answer the question now if you don't finish asking it until "later"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    jsonb_agg(t1.*)  
from (
    SELECT 
        station.id AS "objectID",
        station.name AS "objectName",
        station.activity,
        'Station'::text AS unit,
        jsonb_build_array( 
            json_build_object('key'::text, 'value'::text),
            json_build_object('key'::text, 'value'::text)
        ) AS "childrenList"
    FROM 
        eqp_stations station
) t1
```